# Can't install csv module

Tags: python, macos, csv, pip

I am a mac user and today I tried installing `csv` today and here is command
`pip install csv`.But unfortunately it returned the following error

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement csv (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for csv
```

I have Python version 2.7.13 and I have installed other dependencies like `scikit-learn,numpy and matplotlib`, but for some reason I can't install `csv`.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

[`csv`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) is part of python's standard library so you don't need to install it with pip.  Just use it with:

```
import csv
```